# React JS: Need Gradient Color in Header

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, linear-gradients

I have this simple project here : https://github.com/bsumanji/firstmobileproject/blob/master/App.js
and need a gradient colors in header background. Please help :)

```js
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const standardColor = {
  headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "blue"}
  
};


export default function App() {

  return (

    
    <NavigationContainer>{/* Rest of your app code */}      
       <Stack.Navigator screenOptions ={standardColor}>
          <Stack.Screen name ="Welcome" component={welcomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name ="Home" component={homeScreen} />
       </Stack.Navigator>
       
    </NavigationContainer>

    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a library, you can achieve the same thing with CSS `linear-gradient()` function.

Example:

```
.className{
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
}
```

Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient())

Comment: this function is not helping :(

Comment: what did you do? can you post a snippet ?